# Is it possible to use one Android phone as a touchpad for another Android phone?

Tags: remote-control, mouse

I really want to control my Android phone with a touchpad. But I don't have a bluetooth keyboard with touchpad. Is it possible to use one Android phone as a touchpad for another Android phone? If so, please explain how to do it.

(I want to see a mouse pointer on my main screen and control it by moving the fingers on the screen of the Android phone used as touchpad).

Comment: Whoever leaves downvotes: please explain the reason.

Comment: @Izzy I suspect there's a downvote reason for "*intention too weird*".

Comment: @iBug not if you think about it. If you've got your finger on the display, you can't look through the finger. There are some use-cases where an external touchpad comes in handy. But you might be right that someone thought differently – which is why I asked to state the reason. Except for very obvious cases (e.g. completely off-topic wall-of-text with gibberish) it's always a good idea to leave a comment. If it's a good reason, OP can learn from it.

Comment: @Izzy And we may soon face questions like *How can I use one Android phone as a joystick/control panel/remote control/external storage/extended battery/camera/microphone/light sensor/proximity detector/ for another Android phone?*

Comment: @Izzy Well, all I have done is found it interesting and voted it back to zero.

Comment: Does your phone have OTG support? You can connect a standard mouse using OTG cable. This may be the easiest option here.

Comment: Hi guys. No I don't want to use a mouse over OTG since I don't know of a good way to use OTG and charge the phone at the same time. Anyway, now that I have come up with the idea for using an Android phone as a touchpad for another Android phone I hope that we find a solution some day. Maybe someone reads this post and starts thinking "hey, that's actually a good idea" and codes an app. Or maybe there already is one. In any case, if in the future someone finds a solution please notify and link in this thread.

Comment: I haven't tried these apps since I don't have another device to test, but perhaps you can try any of the apps mentioned on [this Android Central forum](https://forums.androidcentral.com/tablet-apps/118453-phone-mouse-trackpad-tablet-via-bluetooth.html).